# How to change the genre id to genre name

Tags: deezer

I just wanted to know how to change the GENRE_ID to show the actual genre name like GENRE_ID: 3 to be pop as an example .
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score -1):

You just have to execute a request on the /genre endpoint with the good ID, described here: http://developers.deezer.com/api/genre

Comment: the problem that it doesn't contains all the genres ,is there a list or something that contains the genres with its ids ?